# SYMFONY ERROR : The "AppBundle\Entity\User" entity has a repositoryClass set to "AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository", but this is not a valid class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

I'm configuring FOSUserBundle in my symfony project and i received this message.

> The "AppBundle\Entity\User" entity has a repositoryClass set to "AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository", but this is not a valid class. Check your class naming. If this is meant to be a service id, make sure this service exists and is tagged with "doctrine.repository_service".

I searched on my parameters, config, database, ... but impossible to register somebody.

When i try to connect myself with login and password from my database, it doesn't work.

app/config/config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: fr

framework:
    #esi: ~
    #translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true
    translator: ~
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }

sensio_framework_extra:
   router:
        annotations: false



fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: blabla@blabla.bla
        sender_name: blabla@blabla.bla
```

app/config/security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            user_checker: security.user_checker
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            anonymous:    true
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login

            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
            #http_basic: ~

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
            #form_login: ~
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

and src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you also share the definition of that repository class?

Comment: where can i find this one? @NicoHaase

Comment: As your code states: it's the class `AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository`

Comment: Exactly, you link your entity to the `UserRepository` but does it actually exist in your project ? Can you show us this class please ?

Comment: i looked on src/AppBundle/ and Vendor/ but there aren't any file starting by "UserRepository". And i never defined myself @UgoT.

Comment: last comment for @NicoHaase too

Comment: So, if there is no such repository, why did you point your entity to it using `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")`?

Comment: Try to remove `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
` line from your entity then

Comment: doctrine orm automaticly generated these file with command-line tool generate:entity

Comment: @UgoT. another error appear : Unable to find the object manager associated with an entity of class "AppBundle\Entity\User".

Comment: Yes I didn't mentioned it but you must replace the line by `* @ORM\Entity`. Remove only the `(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")` part.